# How can I link between two repos when one uses yarn and the other npm?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I'm using `yarn` in my repo (X), and this project is dependent on a repo (Y), which uses `npm`.

When I want to work locally with both projects and make changes in both of them, I'm trying to link between them:
Repo Y: `npm link`
Repo X: `yarn link Y`

But `yarn` doesn't recognise repo Y.
Moreover, `yarn link` on repo Y and or `npm link Y` on repo X obviously doesn't work either.

How can link between these two repos?